# PAGE_GUARD with VirtualProtect not raising an exception on execute access

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

I'm trying to hook a function using PAGE_GUARD but it does not raise any exception when the page/address is called.

```
void HookMe(){
    printf("Not hooked\n");
}
void GoodFnc(){
    printf("Hooked!\n");
}
long ExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ex){
    printf("ExceptionHandler called\n");
}
/*Called by CreateThread in main*/
DWORD WINAPI ExceptionTesting(LPVOID) {
    DWORD old = 0;
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, ExceptionHandler);
    if (VirtualProtect((LPVOID)HookMe, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &old))
        printf("PAGE_GUARD set\n");
    //This was for testing:
    //*(char*)0 = 0;//ExceptionHandler gets called when ACCESS_VIOLATION happens
    while (1) {
        HookMe();
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code above will only show `PAGE_GUARD set` and then `Not hooked` each second, without raising any kind of exception.

I've also made sure that `HookMe()` is in a different memory page than `ExceptionHandler(...)` and `ExceptionTesting(LPVOID)`

Causing any kind of exception such as ACCESS_VIOLATION(as seen in the comment above the infinite loop) will result in ExceptionHandler being called.

Comment: AFAIK, ``VirtualProtect`` won't throw any exception. You should check if the function failed or succeeded and if it failed then call ``GetLastError``

Comment: It does succeed (`printf("PAGE_GUARD set\n");` gets called). There isn't any exception raised when HookMe() is called in the loop though

Comment: are you test under debugger ? anyway you page_guard set not to single function address but on 1 page (0x1000 bytes). all your code can became in page guard after such protect.

Comment: and your code anyway invalid, will be even not compiled. are this is pseudo code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, depending on your compiler, that the call to `HookMe` is inlined. Inspect the generated code. You should be able to defeat this with something like `__declspec(noinline)` on the declaration of `HookMe`. (MS VC++). Note that you can take the address of a function even if it is inlined at all calls!

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) says that addresses being protected must be part of a reserved region acquired by using `VirtualAlloc` (or `VirtualAllocEx`).  Code within your program was not allocated this way.

Also, the protection is done on a page basis (usually 4K), so likely *all* of the code in your example above would be protected, and the guard would go off immediately when the call to `VirtualProtect` returned - not when `Hook` was called.

Comment: To your first point it is likely that the code was put in a region acquired with `VirtualAlloc` - it's just that that allocation was done by the loader!  But your second point is very interesting - I'm wondering what happened there.  The last paragraph of the Remarks of the MSDN page you linked is probably relevant there: No call to `FlushInstructionCache` was made so it might have to do with inconsistency there.

Comment: BTW w.r.t. your user profile, @1201 - Omnikey keyboards rule!  Especially the old ones with the functions keys on the top _and also on the left, where God put them!_

Comment: your first point is wrong. page guard can be set to any memory

Answer (score 1):

about [`VirtualProtect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Changes the protection on a region of committed **pages** in the
>   virtual address space of the calling process.

**PAGES** - not single byte. we can set `PAGE_GUARD` attribute at least on page (0x1000) byte only. as result when you try set `PAGE_GUARD` to some function - you set guard attribute not only to it but to many bytes around it (before and after). in case code such your (anyway your code is pseudo code, which not compile even) - faster of all guard exception will be just after `VirtualProtect` return - on next instruction after call. if you want only single function affect by guard page - you need place it in separate exe section, say with [`#pragma code_seg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/code-seg). also can note - that not needs any infinite loops or separate threads create for test

```
//#pragma code_seg(".guard")
void HookMe(){
    MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"HookMe", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
#pragma code_seg()

LONG NTAPI ExceptionHandler(::PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pep)
{
    if (pep->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION)
    {
        WCHAR msg[64];
        swprintf(msg, L"guard violation at %p (%p)", pep->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress, HookMe);
        MessageBoxW(0, msg, L"ExceptionHandler", MB_ICONWARNING);
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void gtest()
{
    if (PVOID pv = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, ExceptionHandler))
    {
        ULONG op;
        if (VirtualProtect(HookMe, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ|PAGE_GUARD, &op))
        {
            HookMe();
        }
        RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(pv);
    }
}
```